# How method overloading works here?

Tags: java

I have two overloaded methods with parameters int and Integer respectively.
when I call print method by passing 5, Why is it calling the first print method.
How it identifies which method to call?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(5);
    }

    static void print(int a) {
        System.out.println("Calling first print");
    }

    static void print(Integer a) {
        System.out.println("Calling second print");
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you are passing a primitive int, it chooses the one with a primitive parameter.

Comment: You could use `Integer.valueOf(5)` and it would choose the second version.

Comment: Autoboxing of int into Integer is activated only if no method accepts the int argument.

Comment: [Here's the JLS section that describes how a method is chosen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Test
{
   static void print( int a )
   {
      System.out.println( "Calling first print" );
   }

   static void print( Integer a )
   {
      System.out.println( "Calling second print" );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      print( 5 );
      print( new Integer(5) );
   }
}
```

`print( 5 );` Will output Calling first print because you are passing 5 which is a premitive.`print( new Integer(5) );`  Will output Calling second print because you are passing 5 as integer object so method `static void print( Integer a )` having higher priority.

Answer (score 3):

Why does the compiler bind a primitive variable passed as parameter to the method with a primitive declared parameter ?
Because it makes sense and the JLS goes in this way.
That is rather the reverse that would be very surprising : you pass an `int` and the compiler chooses the method that boxes it to `Integer` instead of selecting the method that has an exact match : an `int` parameter.

Similarly, when you invoke  `print(Integer.valueOf(5))` where `Integer.valueOf()` returns an `Integer` and not an `int`, the method selected by the compiler is the method with the `Integer` as parameter.

> How it identifies which method to call?

In Java, the compiler chooses the most specific method that it founds according to the type declared of the passed parameter. Here it is straight.  Things are less obvious as the match is not direct.

[15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) should interest you.

Comment: [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) is much more relevant, imo

Answer (score 2):

```
 print( 5 );
```

By default 5 is of primitive type.So it calls the first print.